# Changing bar colours in a plotly graph with secondary y-axis in R

Tags: r, colors, plotly

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change the colour of the bars in this graph. I'm sure it's not as complex as I'm making it out to be and would appreciate some help. I've included some dummy data as the actual data I'm using is confidential.

```
covid_hospital_2 <- tibble(`Format Date` = as.Date(c('2022-01-01','2022-02-01','2022-03-01','2022-04-01','2022-05-01','2022-06-01','2022-07-01','2022-08-01','2022-09-01','2022-10-01')),
              `Total Inpatients` = c(180,67,100,89,123,50,134,99,101,170),
              `Proportion in ICU` = c(0.41,0.18,0.33,0.12,0.05,0.15,0.22,0.02,0.29,0.07))

covid_hosp_plot_v2 <- plot_ly(covid_hospital_2, x = ~`Format Date`, y = ~`Total Inpatients`, type = 'bar', name = 'Total Inpatients') |> 
  add_trace(x = ~`Format Date`, y = ~`Proportion in ICU`, type = 'scatter', mode = 'line', yaxis = 'y2', name = 'Proportion in ICU', line = list(color = '#17375E')) |> 
  layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = 'y', side = 'right', tickformat = '.0%', title = 'Proportion in ICU', range = c(0, 1)),
         margin = list(l = 50, r = 50, b = 50, t = 50),
         xaxis = list(tickformat = '%Y-%m-%d', dtick = 'M1', tickangle = -90, title = ''),
         yaxis = list(title = 'Total inpatients', range = c(0, max(covid_hospital_2$`Total Inpatients`))),
         legend = list(x = 0.3, y = -0.25, orientation = 'h'))

covid_hosp_plot_v2
```

[image: Chart with secondary y-axis]

I have tried using Chat GPT but it says to add a markers attribute to the add_trace function but that just adds markers to the line. I have also checked other questions in Stack Overflow but couldn't find anything that matched.

I'd like the colour of the bars to be '#84BDDC'

Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the line color, you have to set the color for the `marker`. To prevent that the marker color is inherited by the line trace I added the bars via a separate `add_trace`:

```r
library(plotly)

covid_hosp_plot_v2 <- plot_ly(covid_hospital_2, x = ~`Format Date`) |> 
  add_trace(
    y = ~`Total Inpatients`, 
    type = "bar",
    name = "Total Inpatients",
    marker = list(color = "#84BDDC")
  ) |>
  add_trace(
    x = ~`Format Date`, y = ~`Proportion in ICU`, type = "scatter",
    mode = "lines", yaxis = "y2", name = "Proportion in ICU",
    line = list(color = "#17375E")
  ) |>
  layout(
    yaxis2 = list(
      overlaying = "y", side = "right", tickformat = ".0%",
      title = "Proportion in ICU", range = c(0, 1)
    ),
    margin = list(l = 50, r = 50, b = 50, t = 50),
    xaxis = list(tickformat = "%Y-%m-%d", dtick = "M1", tickangle = -90, title = ""),
    yaxis = list(
      title = "Total inpatients",
      range = c(0, max(covid_hospital_2$`Total Inpatients`))
    ),
    legend = list(x = 0.3, y = -0.25, orientation = "h")
  )

covid_hosp_plot_v2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be something so simple!